# Session Variables from Registration Form not being passed to Login Form

Tags: php, forms, session, mysqli

I've been trying to troubleshoot a problem I have but I've had no luck so far.

I have a profile page that echoes the user's first and last name. This function works when users first register. The problem is, however, that when the user logs out (ending session) and logs back in and goes back to his/her profile page, the first and last names do not show, leaving instead blanks.

To better clarify consider the pathways:

1.User registers -> profile displays first and last name
2.User logs in -> profile does not display first and last name

Here are the codes pertaining to this issue (I already have session_start() at the top of each page I have; also, my variables, reg form and login form are under one php enclosure):

Variables:

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
     $reg = $_POST['reg'];
     //initializing registration variables to prevent errors
     $fn = ""; //first name
     $ln = ""; //last name
     $em = ""; //email
     $em2 = ""; //email 2
     $pass = ""; //password
     $bday = ""; //birthday
     $sud = ""; //sign up date
     $em_check =""; //check if email exists
     //registration variables + form
     $fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
     $ln = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
     $em = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
     $em2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email2']);
     $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
     $bday = date("Y");
     $sud = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); // Year - Month - Day
```

Registration Form:

```
    if(isset($_POST['reg'])) {
if($em==$em2) {
//check if email already exists
  $emSQLI = "SELECT email FROM `users` WHERE email='$em'";
  $em_check = mysqli_query($con, $emSQLI); //checks whether both entered emails are identical
  $check = mysqli_num_rows($em_check); //count the amount of rows where email = $em
  if ($check == 0) {
    //check if all fields have been filled
    if($fn && $ln && $em && $em2 && $pass && $bday) {
      //check the maximum length of relevant fields
      if(strlen($fn)>90||strlen($ln)>90) {
        echo "Maximum limit for first/last names is 90 characters.";
      }
      else{
        if (strlen($pass)<6||strlen($pass)>99) {
          echo "Password must be between 6 and 99 characters long.";
        }
        else {
          $pass = md5($pass);
          $regSQLI = "INSERT INTO users (id, email, birth_date, first_name, last_name, password, sign_up_date, activated) VALUES ('','$em','$bday','$fn','$ln','$pass','$sud','0')";
          $regQuery = mysqli_query($con, $regSQLI);
       //variables that will be passed over from the register fields to forthcoming sessions
      $_SESSION["email_login"] = $em;
      $_SESSION["first_name"] = $fn;
      $_SESSION["last_name"] = $ln;
      }
      }
      header("location: profile.php");
      exit();
      }
      else {
        echo '<div id="regerrormsg">Please fill in all required fields. </div>';
      }
    }
    else {
      echo '<div id="regerrormsg"> Email is already registered. </div>';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo '<div id="regerrormsg">Entered emails do not match. </div>';
  }
}
```

Log In Form:

```
    if(isset($_POST['email_login']) && isset($_POST['pass_login'])) {
  $email_login = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email_login']);
  $pass_login = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pass_login']);
  $pass_login = md5($pass_login);
  $logquery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password='$pass_login' LIMIT 1";
  $sqli = mysqli_query($con, $logquery);
  $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli); // Count number of rows returned
  // checks the database for respective items
  if ($userCount == 1) { //if the search finds a matching record of the login input form
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqli)) { // use fetch_assoc
          $id = $row["id"];
          }
      $_SESSION["email_login"] = $email_login;
      $_SESSION["first_name"] = $fn;
      $_SESSION["last_name"] = $ln;


      header("location: home.php");
      exit();
  }
  else {
    echo '<div id="regerrormsg">Login information is invalid. </div>';
  }
    }
```

And finally, the profile page that displays the names:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php");

    if(!isset($_SESSION["email_login"])) {
      header("location: index.php");
     exit();
    }

    else {

    }

    ?>

    <?php
    echo "Delighted to have you here, " .$_SESSION["first_name"]."&nbsp".$_SESSION["last_name"].".";
     ?>
```

I am stuck and would like help in troubleshooting this, thank you!

EDIT: Here are the html codes:

Login Form:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
      <input type="email" name="email_login" size="60" placeholder="Email" /><br /><br /><br />
      <input type="password" name="pass_login" size="60" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="LOG IN">
    </form>
```

Register Form:

```
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
          <input type="text" name="first_name" size="15" placeholder="First name" /><br /><br /><br />
          <input type="text" name="last_name" size="15" placeholder="Last name" /><br /><br /><br />
          <input type="email" name="email" size="15" placeholder="Email" /><br /><br /><br />
          <input type="email" name="email2" size="25" placeholder="Re-enter email" /><br /><br /><br />
          <input type="password" name="password" size="15" placeholder="New password" /><br /><br /><br />
          <p5>Birthyear</p5><br />
          <div id="date1" class="datefield">
            <input id="birth_year" type="tel" name="birth_year" maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up"><br />
        </form>
```

Comment: Do you call `session_start()` in the login page?

Comment: Why do you need a `while` loop around the fetch when there's only one row?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, the login and register form along with all of the variables are all on the same php page with session_start() at the very top. As to you second question, it was the only method that came to mind at the time. Thanks.

Comment: Use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and make sure you're not getting a warning about "headers already sent".

Comment: @Barmar Yes I already have that at the very top of my variables. No error is displayed so I don't know the exact issue. It appears that the data is not getting retrieve through log in for some reason.

Comment: BTW, you should only use `mysqli_real_escape_string` for strings you're putting into queries. You shouldn't use this for session variables.

Comment: @Barmar Huh, I didn't think I was doing to that my session , I will look into that. However, how will that help me in troubleshooting my original problem?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the original problem. It's just a comment about your code.

Comment: @CodeMerchant Can you add this code `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);` after your `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` ? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Log form`, replace this

```
  $logquery = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password='$pass_login' LIMIT 1";
  $sqli = mysqli_query($con, $logquery);
  $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli); // Count number of rows returned
  // checks the database for respective items
  if ($userCount == 1) { //if the search finds a matching record of the login input form
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqli)) { // use fetch_assoc
          $id = $row["id"];
          }
      $_SESSION["email_login"] = $email_login;
      $_SESSION["first_name"] = $fn; // -> $fn not defined
      $_SESSION["last_name"] = $ln; // -> $ln not defined


      header("location: home.php");
      exit();
  }
  else {
    echo '<div id="regerrormsg">Login information is invalid. </div>';
  }
```

**By this**

```
  $logquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email_login' AND password='$pass_login' LIMIT 1";
  $sqli = mysqli_query($con, $logquery);
  $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sqli); // Count number of rows returned
  // checks the database for respective items
  if ($userCount == 1) { //if the search finds a matching record of the login input form
      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqli)) { // use fetch_assoc
          $id = $row["id"];
          $_SESSION["email_login"] = $row["email"];
          $_SESSION["first_name"] = $row["first_name"]; // -> retrieve the data from the result of the query
          $_SESSION["last_name"] = $row["last_name"];
      }
      // EDIT: i moved the $_SESSION part above, my bad !


      header("location: home.php");
      exit();
  }
  else {
    echo '<div id="regerrormsg">Login information is invalid. </div>';
  }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hello, thank you for helping me, however with your suggestion I am unable to log in. After clicking login I am not directed to home.php; instead, nothing happens and I am still on the front page.

Comment: Why do you think `$fn` and `$ln` are not defined? He assigns them at the top of the script: `$fn = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);`

Comment: @CodeMerchant Hi ! Thanks for the test. Can you show us the Log In form html ? please

Comment: @zilongqiu Yeah, I included them in the edit of the OP.

Comment: @Barmar `$fn` and `$ln` are defined via $_POST['first_name'] and $_POST['last_name'] which are defined on the registration page. So after an logout, the user login page doesn't have these $_POST values stored anymore in $_SESSION. My english is very bad sorry !

Comment: Good point. Even though the forms are on the same page, the user isn't going to fill in the registration form when he's logging into an existing account.

Comment: @Barmar Absolutly ! ;)

Comment: @CodeMerchant I fixed an issue in my post with `$_SESSION["email_login"] = $row["email"]; ...`  which was define outside of the loop `while`.

Comment: @zilongqiu Monsieur, thank you so very much, I am new to coding thus still unsophisticated in my coding. You have relieved me of my headaches, thanks a bunch! Not only that, but your explanation has made the issue easier and clearer to understand; I will be sure not to make the same mistake!